# "Lantern effect" or show only a part of a scene

Tags: opengl, light, operation, polygons

I'm trying to show only a part of a background image (game scenenario in the future). The basic way to work is for example, first I draw a background image, after that i need to "hide"/cover the image with some dark or darness (no light, don't know what option must be chosen) and use the mouse click to using a circle or a triangle (my options) show only the part of the image background over with the circle/triangle centered on mouse position. I called this "lantern effect".

**First Option**: Play with the alpha channel, creating a an square covering all the window size and after that trying to substract the circle area over the alpha square over the image.

**Second Option**: Play again with a black square covering all the image background and trying to substract a circle/triangle. Try with glLogicOp but this method only plays mixing colors. Don't know how to do operation with 2D polygons with OpenGL.

...

Any other idea or easy example to learn how to do something similar.

Image example:
[image: Lantern Effect]

Comment: "and use the mouse click to using a circle or a triangle (my options) show only the part of the image background over with the circle/triangle centered on mouse position" Can you explain this a bit more? I'm hazy how you want to control showing the background.

Comment: @genpfault Do you have an image that would illustrate the effect you are trying to achieve? Something like this maybe? http://spheredev.org/smforums/index.php?topic=10381.0

Answer (score 1):

That's quite easy to achieve actually:

1. Create black texture with your lantern light shape in Alpha channel. (Texture could be animated)
2. Render background.
3. Render Lantern texture centered at your in-game mouse cursor.
4. Render black padding around the lantern texture to hide everything around till screen edges.

There's no need to use any special blending modes, just an overlay.

Comment: That's other option i take in care. But i ask if there is other option.

Comment: This is Q&A site. You formulate the question and people answer it. If you already have a working answer, then why do you ask for another one? Perhaps you should rephrase your question so to **clearly state why 2 existing solution are not acceptable**.